# Controller or View

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, laravel

I have always coded controllers so that they simply call data from a model and then present that data to the view:

```
class ProjectViewModel
{
    public $User = NULL; // Contains authentication levels etc    
    public $Projects = NULL;
}

class ProjectController
{
    //...

    public function ListProjects()
    {
        $viewModel = new ProjectViewModel();
        $viewModel->User = $this->sessionRepository->GetSession();
        $viewModel->Projects = $this->projectRepository->Projects();
        return View::make( "ViewName", $viewModel );
    }
}
```

Now in my view:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach( $Model->Projects as $project ) { ?>
        <li>
            <?=$project->Title?>
            <?php
                switch( $Model->User->Authentication->Type )
                {
                    case AuthenticationType::ADMIN:
                        | <button>Edit</button>
                    break;
                }
            ?>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

You see in **my way of doing things**, the person designing the view decides what is shown based off of the user's authentication... Don't take this just for how I have made it too, you can think about the model returning projects with a property that states whether they can or cannot edit a specific project... The main idea is there is 1 Boolean value that states if someone can or cannot do something to a project.

**My colleague** has gone for a different approach, which is interesting because he is defining within the controller, if a "button" (which may or may not exist if the view person decides to show it in a different way) should be shown or not:

```
class ProjectController
{
    //...

    public function ListProjects()
    {
        $viewModel = new ProjectViewModel();
        $viewModel->User = $this->sessionRepository->GetSession();
        $viewModel->Projects = $this->projectRepository->Projects(); 
        $viewModel->Buttons = array(
           "EditButton" => array(
               "Name" => "Edit button",
               "Show" => ( $viewModel->User == AuthenticationType::ADMIN ) ? TRUE : FALSE
           ),               
           "OpenProjectReportButton" => array(
               "Name" => "Open project report",
               "Show" => ( $viewModel->User == AuthenticationType::ADMIN ) ? TRUE : FALSE
           )
        );
        return View::make( "ViewName", $viewModel );
    }
}
```

In the view he uses buttons that have been pre-declared in the controller:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach( $Model->Projects as $project ) { ?>
        <li>
            <?=$project->Title?> 
            <?php if( $project[ "EditButton" ][ "Show" ] ) { ?>
                <button><?$project[ "EditButton" ][ "Name" ]?></button>                
            <?php } ?>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Although I understand why he might think this is a good idea, The controller is now taking on some of the work of the view... In fact he has gone as far as to say that the view will have buttons.. which the designer may disagree with...

It also means that if the view guy wants to add another button somewhere else, he's going to have to ask the controller guy to give him a new button in the array for something else... and just after doing that, he may then say, actually it's not a button, I just want to show an image instead...

Am I right in thinking this is wrong?

**Overview:**

- A controller should fetch data from the model, and push it to the view for the view to display it how it wants to display it...
  A **view** should use that data to decide how and what to show on the view... ( further more to this, if you are worried that an admin button is shown accidently, if they click on that button provided by the view engineer, it doesn't matter.. the user get's taken to another page which loads a controller which insists that actually, this user does not have access to this page... )
- The view guy should be asking questions like, can this user edit projects... rather than have I been given a button that I can display to the view

What if the view guy decided actually, for design purposes, I want to show buttons that the user can't use... and provide a message stating why he can't use it... The controller in my colleagues example has provided a list of buttons that will now have to be ignored considering the view engineer (artist/designer) is decided actually, screw your controller... I want to show that button!

Am I right?

EDIT:: I've added new tags because i'm aware that PHP and C# people have very different approaches to problems... and i'm interested in the view from asp.net users aswell.

Comment: You're not right, and you're not wrong.Either way is acceptable. What you have to look at is the development method and model you want to work with. If you have several different people performing different tasks, such as one for controller actions and 1 for views, then your way lends itself a little better. However, from a code security aspect, his way works better.

Comment: There are multiple approaches to how you build your own code. Fat controllers vs. skinny Controllers, Business Models vs. POPO Models, complex Views/Templates vs. Renders + simple Templates.

Comment: Some prefer and promote logic-less templating as the only way to really implement separation of concerns (ex.: [this great article](http://www.mujweb.cz/mkanturek/mvc.templates.pdf) by Terence Parr).

Comment: @tereško what purpose is it for a controller to decide what an artist is to put in the view... when the artist can ignore what the controller gives to them to display anyway! Surely the controller should be literally not allowing access to the controller if someone manages to navigate to that controller? not the controller worrying about VIEW related stuff? What on earth is the point in separating view and controller when the controller is telling the view engineer he is not free to design the view however he desires?..

Comment: In my opinion Controllers should hold "logic that does not relate to the business" or "logic that only relates to the IT infrastructure". Thus the controller should just call a Service which enacts the business logic while the controller retains the transactions, locks, redirections, etc..

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 controllers responsibility is to alter the state of the model layer. And views responsibility is to produce UI based on data that the view gets from model layer. Also, **please stop with the pointless anthropomorphization.**

Comment: From my earlier point of view that means View logic shouldn't be inside a Controller. And since Services store Business Logic, it shouldn't be there either. So Renderers (classes that help rendering) should contain that logic which means keeping the templates clean(er) of logic too.

Answer (score 1):

Proper MVC separation is simply only about separating responsibilities appropriately:

- the model does all the work, everything your application "can do" is part of a thick model layer
- the view visualises the state of the model, i.e. what's going on in your app, to the user (or to other entities)
- the controller mostly just reacts to events (input) and directs them to appropriate actions to make something happen in the model and refresh the view if necessary; it's the plumbing between model, view and the rest of the world

As such, it's none of the controller's business to do anything which has to do with presentation. The view is also not simply a single .php HTML template. The view can be as thick as the model layer and its responsibility is to do anything that's necessary to produce useful output. The view should directly talk to the model to get the state information it needs as appropriate. Pretty much all of the code that's currently in your controller belongs into the view.

Comment: Sorry, what? It doesn't matter "whose" controller it is. A controller does not contain any code that deals with "buttons", period. That's none of its business, it's the view's.

Comment: @Deceze Still breaking a "View" into a Renderer class and a Template file would help structure code and possibly code reuse.

Comment: If you see my question, I have put my version of a controller and my colleagues version of a controller.. thus you are saying.. my version is the correct one.. Thanks

Comment: @Mihai Absolutely. As I say, the view is not simply a single HTML template which needs to be fed by the controller.

Comment: @Jimmy Your controller is also doing too much. It's fetching data for the view. That means the controller takes on responsibility of preparing the data the view needs. That's not its job. The controller should load the appropriate view and pass it some object that allows the view to retrieve the data it needs from the model.

Comment: @deceze - Your opinion then is strange to me, because people like Adam Freemans Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 book puts model calls into the controller.. but I see that no one actually bloody knows the correct answer.. and if things are to be misinterpreted like the bible is, then this whole mvc thing seems useless lol! whether it be me or you wrong

Comment: @Jimmy An trivial example of a controller: `$view = new SomeView($serviceFactory); $view->displayProfileForUser($_GET['userid']);` - that's all the controller needs to do. The rest is up to the view and the model.

Comment: @deceze what about if the user doesn't have the right to see this profile? Or if he is not authenticate?
Do you check the rights of the user inside the views or in the controllers part?

Comment: @Jimmy Well, there is not *one* answer, surely. Simply consider that the model is irreplaceable, it's "your app". The view is interchangeable, there are many different "visualisations" you can employ for your app. The controller is interchangeable depending on what "real world context" the app is run in. This should very much inform which code goes where. If you put too much code into a controller which you'd have to repeat if you need to use a different controller but the same view, then it was the wrong place for that code.

Comment: @Ballantine The controller needs to instruct the model to establish its state (who's logged in?), then ask the model if the logged in user is allowed to do something ("view profile X"), and then decide which view to present (UserProfileView or NotAllowedView).

Comment: I've been developing in mvc for 3 years... I have always put model calls into the controller to push them to the view( unchanged.. if anything changes, that needs to stay in the model).. the controller gets stuff form the model.. and puts it into the view...

A view then for example, submits a form... the form gets sent to a controller.. which then puts the views data through into the model... the model manipulates the database... etc and so on.

Comment: Again @Jimmyt1988, sing it with me: MVC, MMVC, Fat Controllers, Skinny Controllers, Business Models, POPO Models, Model Views, Renderers+Helpers+Logic-less Views... flavours over flavours of MVC implemented just the way the architect saw fit to do it...

Comment: Check out Zend MVC, check out Magento MVC, check out Symfony2, check out any other MVC; you'll inevitably notice there is not golden standard or bible reference. There is only the task at hand, the foresight you had for the foreboding problems you thought you would solve with your particular flavour of architecture.

Comment: @Jimmy Again, just consider... may you have a website, a REST API and a CLI interface for your app? How much controller code would these three very different types of interaction share? Not much. How much model code would they share? All. How much view code would they share? Maybe some. If you can do the same action in all three interaction types, how much code do you need to duplicate for each different controller? Might that code not better belong into either the model or the view?

Comment: This is why I like maths... There's usually only one answer to something lol... development is a battlefield of how people perceive things... I just can't understand my colleagues views of the controller.. it's stupid...

Controller should not do ANYTHING with a view, or even suggest how it should be... NEVER, it's a total anti-pattern.

If you are going to do the above, you better put another bloody layer in which belongs to the view part of the application... We'd call it the, HoldingBackADesignerView layer

Comment: I always made my MVC like @Jimmyt1988, and I know there are a lot a 'different' kind of MVC. I think I'll make a try of deceze point of view...

Comment: @Ballantine - On the fence.. I wish it's where I had stayed... lol...

Comment: From many perspectives the Symfony2 code structuring guidelines will make you create a lot of small little files but in the interest of KISS and making sure one function/method accomplishes one thing and one thing only it's a pretty clear and well grouped structure.

Comment: Controllers and Commands (CLIs) contain technology logic something that glues the Business logic to HTTP or CLI environments and helps it work. Hence they are thin and handle only locking, db transactions, http redirects, and other top-level non-business logic.

Comment: @Jimmy Also note that the particulars of MVC may be implemented rather differently in different languages because of different structures. PHP is notoriously constantly started and torn down again and communicates via HTTP. This creates very different basics for creating views. You'd do some entirely different structure in, say, client-side Javascript or a desktop app, because the model, controller and view are permanently running side by side. In that situation you have a lot of of small events which need to be routed, instead of whole templates which need to be rendered.

Comment: Services handle the business logic and isolate it from technical contexts so that you can reuse the services in multiple Controllers or Commands etc..

Comment: Entities (Models) are Plain Old PHP Objects which "talk" to the DB. Repositories keep complex (parametrized, reusable) queries to help talk to the DB.

Comment: @MihaiStancu - In terms of what you said, I'm not sure this ties in exactly with what i'm going to say but... I find that having a set of repositories in the model whose methods are called by the controllers... this epository layer allows for interfacing and Controller/Dependancy injection... which serves well when you have possibilities of database sources changing underneath you... Then a controller has no idea where the data comes from, just that it has some models that always expose certain methods... This was first introduced to me in Asp.NET Microsoft Unity, but now in laravel too!

Comment: Views in Symfony2 are more or less templates but nothing is stopping you from creating a service or a standalone class to help you prepare model data for display in a template and in the case of Forms this is even (more or less) encouraged.

Comment: That's what we call a ViewModel... sometimes you have to prepare a bit more stuff for one view... the viewmodel never deals with any modification of the data, but it just holds the stuff in a strong typed way, so that the view for that controller can get all the info you think it needs

Comment: Meh, major projects won't be replatforming their RDBMS like crazy and they also most of the time need raw SQL queries which would need to be rewritten. So replatforming is more of a partial goal "make it easier" in the event of a replatforming, not "make it drop-in replaceable".

Comment: @MihaiStancu - I had a project set up with using an API... half way through we discovered the API was just too slow to serve the data... In my Dependancy bindings, I change it from APIProjectRepository to SQLProjectRepository... it forced me to implement all of the get and delete and whatever methods (because of my interface)... and it saved me a complete headache... everything just worked and I had literally changed the entire applications data source over!!! Epic my friend!

Comment: Using one module only by its publicly exposed API interface is very good practice with the purpose of (possibly) replacing it with either a different better module or with an async publisher on another machine (instead of a sync module).

Comment: But many things cannot be used as simple 3rd party service providers with limited interfaces. In that respect the raw SQL example is good. Since for example Doctrine2 doesn't allow some batching operations (ex.: INSERTs, or UPDATEs with join tables) or in some contexts it eats up memory with two spoons. In those cases you end up writing raw SQL code and you can't just replace Doctrine2 with another module. Besides Doctrine2 expioses a huge API which is not covered by interfaces so you can't drop-in replace it with Eloquent. So you're vendor-locked.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things, first expanding on what deceze said:

> "Pretty much all of the code that's currently in your controller
>   belongs into the view"

I agree, your controller is junked up with stuff that shouldn't be there.  Your controller should look like this:

```
class ProjectController
{
    public function ListProjects()
    {
        return View::make("ViewName");
    }
}
```

The data preparation works better inside Laravel's ViewComposers.

In Laravel they have a construct called the ViewComposer.  It is designed to prepare data for your views.

You specify a class called:

```
class ViewNameComposer {

    public function compose($view){
        $view->model = new ProjectViewModel();
        $view->model->User = $this->sessionRepository->GetSession();
        $view->model->Projects = $this->projectRepository->Projects();
    }
}
```

And then you register it with the view:

```
View::composer('ViewName', 'ViewNameComposer');
```

And when that view is rendered the composer hooks in and prepares the data for the view.

What is really awesome is that you can associate ViewComposer with partial view snippets.

This means that when you are using say the Blade templating engine and your page view has a boolean that determines whether or not to display some "other content", if you save that "other content" as a partial view snippet and conditionally include it

```
@if($someBool)
    @include ('partials.ViewName.othercontent')
@endif
```

then you can only load the data that the partials.ViewName.othercontent needs (from the ViewComposer of partials.ViewName.othercontent) if it needs it.

What I like about this approach is it helps keep the views a bit cleaner and it gets rid of the junk that shouldn't be in the controller.

For more information on ViewComposers check out their documentation:

http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers

Comment: Oh well that's a benefit too! I always liked the idea of having yet another layer outside of the controller for the view composition! I didn't know Laravel had a built in layer for that... me likey bread stick.

I have separated my view layer into that ViewModel... This technique is taken from Adam Freemans Asp.NET MVC Pro book

Comment: What you're describing is simply the internal structure of the view. The "ViewComposer" is one part of the view. I totally agree that this is a neat and necessary thing to do. Again, views aren't simply single HTML template files. :)

Comment: I just saw this: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers which seems to say that how I have done it is in keeping with the laravel way too!.. and also the asp.net mvc way... Alas I am digging this ViewComposer layer, it's sexy mann

Comment: I agree with this answer, it's clean, uses blade, simple and implements view composers. Top notch

Comment: deceze you are right, I think of the view as the template, but at a more abstract level the the ViewComposer is part of the view.  I have edited the way I state the answer to represent that.

Comment: Jimmyt1988 you should check out https://laracasts.com/. There are lots of good resources there.

Comment: You really should stop pretending that Laravel implements anything even remotely like MVC.